# Recycling ListView rows with different row layouts

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

I have a `ListView` adapter which is set with different layouts according to the type of the row item.

If I recycle my rows using a holder, as shown in the code below, I think I'll get some errors because for a recycled row I'll get the layout of the latest non-recycled row, which might not be of the same type.

Should I avoid recycling the rows in that case? What other options do I have?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    MyHolder holder = null;

    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    if(row == null)
    {           
        holder = new MyHolder();

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();

        if(type == TYPE_1){
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_type_1, parent, false);
        }
        else if(type == TYPE_2){
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_type_2, parent, false);
        }               
        else {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_type_3, parent, false);
        }

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (MyHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Are you overriding getViewTypeCount and getItemViewType?

Comment: Recycling with RecyclerView and multiple row layout sample demo http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/10/android-multiple-row-layout-using.html where recycling is handled recycler itself

Comment: Use the recycleView instead of the listview, Check below link it inflates the different rows in the recyclview http://stackoverflow.com/a/39972276/3946958

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always recycle rows!  Your implementation of `getItemViewType` (and `getViewTypeCount`) instructs the `ListView` when to recycle what types of views so that they won't get mixed up.

Your code snippet looks good. So, it all should work. The only slightly odd part is the `if(type == TYPE_3)`. Did you mean `if(type == TYPE_2)`?

The question is: Do you have problem/exception in your code right now?

Comment: Yes if(type == TYPE_3) was a typo. Thanks.

Comment: @Streets Of Boston, sorry for pinging this way. It's very urgent for me. Pls help me out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47897770/issues-in-using-edittext-in-row-of-recyclerview-and-the-textwatcher-on-edittext?noredirect=1#comment82874592_47897770

Answer (score 2):

> If I recycle my rows using a holder, as shown in the code below, I
>   think I'll get some errors because for a recycled row I'll get the
>   layout of the latest non-recycled row, which might not be of the same
>   type.

If you are referring to the `row == null` check, then there is no problem as the `ListView` will give you the right `convertView` according to the `getItemViewType()` method.

If you are referring to the `MyHolder` class this again is not a problem because the holder is set as the tag for the row view and if the `ListView` gives you the right recycled row view then the holder tag will also have the proper fields initialized in it for that type of row. And, as you should handle the `MyHolder` according to the row type this isn't a problem as you'll access the initialized fields. Your `MyHolder` class should have references for all the views that your three type of rows expose so you have where to put them.

So keep the recycling mechanism.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the row == null check. Thanks for the explanation. I'll accept Streets Of Boston's answer because he was first.

Comment: @Luksprog, sorry for pinging this way. It's very urgent for me. Pls help me out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47897770/issues-in-using-edittext-in-row-of-recyclerview-and-the-textwatcher-on-edittext?noredirect=1#comment82874592_47897770