# Recycle-view inflating different row :- Getting exception while binding the data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on the `Recyceview` with different item inflation. When i am **NOT** binding the data on `onBindViewHolder` method of `RecycleView` than it Does not crash..
But when i am binding the data inside the `onBindViewHolder` than i am getting the `Exception`, Please check my code and let me know where am i doing wrong.

```
package com.tv.practise.adapter;

  /**
    Created by Ravindra Kushwaha on 10/10/16.
   */

public class RecycleDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<RecycleBen> data;

public static class SimpleText extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView first_data_tv;

    public SimpleText(View v) {
        super(v);
        this.first_data_tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.first_data_tv);
    }
}

public   class SimpleImage extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView second_data_iv;

    public SimpleImage(View v) {
        super(v);
        this.second_data_iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.second_data_iv);
    }
}

public  class SimpleImageWithText extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView third_data_tv;
    ImageView third_iv;

    public SimpleImageWithText(View v) {
        super(v);
        this.third_data_tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.third_data_tv);
        this.third_iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.third_iv);
    }
}

public RecycleDataAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<RecycleBen> data) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public  RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    int listViewItemType = getItemViewType(viewType);
    View itemView;
    if(listViewItemType==1)
    {

        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycle_first_item, parent, false);

        return new SimpleText(itemView

        );

    }
    else if(listViewItemType==2)
    {
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycle_fsecond_item, parent, false);
        return new SimpleImage(itemView);
    }
    else
    {
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycle_third_item, parent, false);
        return new SimpleImageWithText(itemView);
    }



}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    RecycleBen bean = data.get(position);

    if(holder.getItemViewType()==1)
    {
           /////HERE I AM GETTING THE EXCEPTION WHILE BINDIND DATA
        ((SimpleText)holder).first_data_tv.setText(bean.getName());

    }
    else if(holder.getItemViewType()==2)
    {

    }
    else {
          /////HERE I AM GETTING THE EXCEPTION WHILE BINDIND DATA((SimpleImageWithText)holder).third_data_tv.setText(bean.getName());
    }

}




@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return Integer.parseInt(data.get(position).getType_row());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
  }
}
```

**Exception** while i am binding the data are as follow:-

```
3758-3758/com.tv.practise E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tv.practise, PID: 3758
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tv.practise.adapter.RecycleDataAdapter$SimpleImageWithText cannot be cast to com.tv.practise.adapter.RecycleDataAdapter$SimpleText
            at com.tv.practise.adapter.RecycleDataAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecycleDataAdapter.java:101)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5471)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5504)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4741)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2625)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2112)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1228)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1464)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6060)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: It should be wrong. I deteled my comment. I am writing another one.

Comment: ok @Joshua .. Waiting for urs response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is`onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)`. The parameter is view type but not position. Using `int listViewItemType = getItemViewType(viewType)` is incorrect because `position` should be passed to `getItemViewType`.

In short, you should use `viewType` directly and remove `listViewItemType` in `onCreateViewHolder`.

Comment: Thanks @Joshua .. It worked.. Now i am accepting yours answer and posting a correct code here for the other users.. Again dost thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

**@Joshua** shorted out my problem..
For the other users i am posting here is the code for inflating the different rows *(3 rows)* in the `RecycleView` 
 And it works fine , check the below lines of the code:- ***I am posting my full code here please check:-***

Here **`RecyleClass.java`** is my main class

```
package com.tv.practise.recycleview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.tv.practise.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Ravindra Kushwaha on 10/10/16.
 */
public class RecyleClass extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recycle_main);

        RecyclerView recycler_vw = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_vw);


        ArrayList<RecycleBen> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0;i<=25;i++)
        {
            RecycleBen bean = new RecycleBen();

            if(i%2==0)
            {

                bean.setType_row("1");
                bean.setName("First element");
                bean.setImage_url("http://www.androhub.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/staggeredrecyclerview_banner.jpg");
            }
            else if(i%3==0)
            {
                bean.setType_row("2");
                bean.setName("Second element");
                bean.setImage_url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/snB84.png");
            }
            else
            {
                bean.setType_row("3");
                bean.setName("Third element");
                bean.setImage_url("http://inducesmile.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/gridbanner.jpg");
            }

            arrayList.add(bean);

        }

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recycler_vw.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recycler_vw.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recycler_vw.setAdapter(new RecycleDataAdapter(this, arrayList));

    }
}
```

Here is the my `layout` for the **`RecyleClass.java`** that is **`recycle_main.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_vw"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Gradles** entry for the `Recycleview` with `CardView` and `Glide`

```
 // CardView
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    // RecyclerView
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'

    // For the glide libraray
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

And below is my the `getter` and `setter` class that is **`RecycleBen.java`**

```
package com.tv.practise.recycleview;

/**
 * Created by Ravindra Kushwaha on 10/10/16.
 */
public class RecycleBen {

    private String type_row;
    private String name;
    private String image_url;


    public String getType_row() {
        return type_row;
    }

    public void setType_row(String type_row) {
        this.type_row = type_row;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImage_url() {
        return image_url;
    }

    public void setImage_url(String image_url) {
        this.image_url = image_url;
    }
}
```

And at the last my Adapter class that is **`RecycleDataAdapter.java`**

```
package com.tv.practise.adapter;

/**
 * Created by Ravindra Kushwaha on 10/10/16.
 */
public class RecycleDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<RecycleBen> data;



    public  class SimpleText extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView first_data_tv;

        public SimpleText(View v) {
            super(v);
            this.first_data_tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.first_data_tv);
        }
    }

    public   class SimpleImage extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView second_data_iv;
        ProgressBar second_pb;

        public SimpleImage(View v) {
            super(v);
            this.second_data_iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.second_data_iv);
            this.second_pb = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.second_pb);
        }
    }

    public  class SimpleImageWithText extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView third_data_tv;
        ImageView third_iv;
        ProgressBar third_pb;

        public SimpleImageWithText(View v) {
            super(v);
            this.third_data_tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.third_data_tv);
            this.third_iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.third_iv);
            this.third_pb = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.third_pb);
        }
    }

    public RecycleDataAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<RecycleBen> data) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public  RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView;
        if(viewType==1)
        {

            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.recycle_first_item, parent, false);

            return new SimpleText(itemView

            );

        }
        else if(viewType==2)
        {
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.recycle_fsecond_item, parent, false);
            return new SimpleImage(itemView);
        }
        else
        {
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.recycle_third_item, parent, false);
            return new SimpleImageWithText(itemView);
        }



    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        RecycleBen bean = data.get(position);

        if(holder.getItemViewType()==1)
        {

            ((SimpleText)holder).first_data_tv.setText(bean.getName());

        }
        else if(holder.getItemViewType()==2)
        {
            final SimpleImage simple_holder = (SimpleImage)holder;



            simple_holder.second_pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(bean.getImage_url())
                    .fitCenter()
                    .crossFade()
                    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            if (e instanceof UnknownHostException)
                                simple_holder.second_pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            simple_holder.second_pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            simple_holder.second_data_iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }).into(simple_holder.second_data_iv);;

        }
        else {

            final SimpleImageWithText third_holder = (SimpleImageWithText)holder;

            third_holder.third_data_tv.setText(bean.getName());

            third_holder.third_pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(bean.getImage_url())
                    .fitCenter()
                    .crossFade()
                    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            if (e instanceof UnknownHostException)
                                third_holder.third_pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            third_holder.third_pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            third_holder.third_iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }).into(third_holder.third_iv);;



        }

    }




    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return Integer.parseInt(data.get(position).getType_row());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
}
```

As we are inflating the different rows in the `Recycleview`, so we used here **3 layout** which are as **`recycle_first_item.xml`** ,**`recycle_fsecond_item.xml`** and last one **`recycle_third_item.xml`**
One by one i am showing all the layout `xml`, which are as follow:-

**recycle_first_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_data_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:text="Hello Card" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**recycle_fsecond_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/second_pb"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/second_data_iv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:src="@drawable/bubble1" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**recycle_third_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/third_data_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Hello Card" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/third_pb"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/third_data_tv"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/third_iv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/third_data_tv"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bubble2"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            />

    </RelativeLayout> 
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

***And finally the result is as below :-***
[image: Result below]

Comment: Perfect Answer!!

Comment: Thanks..Around 4 years later, getting appreciation ☺️

Comment: Here's a link to a repo of a demo app based on this code: https://github.com/n-anselm/MultiViewAdapterRecyclerViewDemo