# dynamic form in a listview

Tags: android, listview, survey

I want to build a dynamic survey with android. Question are created from a server a loaded in my Android app through rest service. Each question has a parameter that indicates the type of the answer. According to the question type, I want a given widget (Edittext, checkboxn...) for input in a listview. Let's asume this is the list of question:

```
"question": [
        {
            "name": "fieldA",
            "type": "STRING",
            "minCharacters": 10,
            "maxCharacters": 100
        },
        {
            "name": "fieldB",
            "type": "INTEGER",
            "min": 10,
            "max": 100
        },
        {
            "name": "fieldC",
            "type": "BOOLEAN",
            "defaultValue": true
        }
    ],
```

What I have done now is to create different layout for each type of question and call in adapter:

boolean_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#5fb0c9"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/questionLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/questionValueCbx"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="Oui/Non"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

string_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#5fb0c9"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/questionLabel"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"/>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/questionValue"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

</LinearLayout>
```

....

And I call the appropriate layout in adapter

```
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            final ViewHolder holder ;
            // questions here refers to the list of questions
            String questionType = questions.get(i).getQuestionType().trim();
            if (view == null || view.getTag() == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                switch (questionType){
                    case "BOOLEAN": {
                        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.boolean_layout, viewGroup,false);
                        holder.tv_questionLable = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.questionLabel);
                        holder.questionAnswer = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.questionValueCbx);
                    }
                    case "STRING": {
                        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.string_question, viewGroup,false);
                        holder.tv_questionLable = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.questionLabel);
                        holder.questionAnswer = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.questionValue);
                    }
                    case "INT": {
                        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.number_question, viewGroup,false);
                        holder.tv_questionLable = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.questionLabel);
                        holder.questionAnswer = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.questionValue);
                    }
...
                }
         }
```

The result does not meets my expectations. It puts Edittext everywhere, even where it is supposed to put checkbox.
Help.

Comment: You need to inflate different layout according to response..have look on this link, it will be helpful for u . https://stackoverflow.com/a/39972276/3946958

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are inflating the different item into the listview than u need to use this method `getItemViewType` of the `BaseAdapter` class.

Have a look into my solution i have distinguished the view and managed accordingly

```
public class YOUR_ADAPTER_CLASS extends BaseAdapter {

    private int ITEM_BOOLEAN = 1;
    private int ITEM_STRING = 2;
    private int ITEM_INT = 3;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return questions.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return questions.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return questions.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {


        if (questions.get(position).getQuestionType().equalsIgnoreCase("BOOLEAN")) {
            return ITEM_BOOLEAN;
        } else if (questions.get(position).getQuestionType().equalsIgnoreCase("STRING")) {
            return ITEM_STRING;
        } else {
            return ITEM_INT;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        int listViewItemType = getItemViewType(position);


        if (convertView == null) {

            if (listViewItemType == ITEM_BOOLEAN) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.boolean_layout, null);

            } else if (listViewItemType == ITEM_STRING) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.string_question, null);
            } else {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.number_question, null);
            }
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        if (listViewItemType == ITEM_BOOLEAN) {

            /**
             * GET THE BOOLEAN ITEM AND INFALTE DATA INTO IT
             */

        } else if (listViewItemType == ITEM_STRING) {
            /**
             * GET THE STRING ITEM AND INFALTE DATA INTO IT
             */

        } else {
            /**
             * GET THE INT ITEM AND INFALTE DATA INTO IT
             */
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

> Have a look on my another solution which is in the Recyclview
>    [Recyclview with different item inflation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971350/recycle-view-inflating-different-row-getting-exception-while-binding-the-data/39972276#39972276)