# Using Multiple Views in a Custom Listview Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, custom-adapter

I am currently in the middle of a project, which involves one Imageview, and one Textview, set up within a custom layout file, and maintained through a custom adapter I have set up.

Everything works fine as it is, the thing is, I would like to have two or even four textviews, and passing in another string array gives me an error. I am a bit stuck here, and will place my code below for you.

### The code:

### The error:

I am sure it is something rather simple I am doing wrong, but either way it is beyond me.

The error can be seen in the image above. How can I do what I am currently doing, but with 2 TVs?

Comment: Hi John..Have a look on this solution, it can be helpful for u https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950438/3946958 .  And another one is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971350/recycle-view-inflating-different-row-getting-exception-while-binding-the-data/39972276#39972276

Comment: Thank you but that did not really help as they are quite different, and I am rather new ^^

Comment: Why are u passing two arrays in the custom adapter...As adapter depend on yours only one arraylist size...U can use the custom ArrayList for it..Like urs text and images can be save in single ArrayList

Comment: Interesting Ravindra, Thank you for that tip, I did not know. Would you be able to perhaps provide an example where I could fill out two TV's, with two different sets of data, like (1, 2, 3) and (a, b, c) ?

Comment: Base adapter looks like an option as well so ty for that ^^

Comment: have a look in below solution and let me know in case of concern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the model class below

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class ListModel implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String image;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

And in your java class, u need to inflate the data like this

```
ArrayList<ListModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) {

    ListModel model = new ListModel();

    model.setName("Name " + i);
    model.setAddress("Address " + i);
    model.setImage("Image " + i);

    arrayList.add(model);
}

// YOU CAN USE THIS LIST IN YOUR ADAPTER JUST PASS YOUR ARRAYLIST INTO ADAPTER
CustomCurationAdaptor adapter = new CustomCurationAdaptor(this, arrayList);
```