# Listview add item one at a time

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, adapter

I have a listview and a button in my main activity and three layout ressource files (right.xml, mid.xml and left.xml [They're relative layout]).

I want to make an arrayList (with strings and drawable (images)) and each time I push the button in main.xml the first content of the arrayList will appear at the bottom of the screen (either left, mid or right --> depend of the order of the arrayList) and when I click again the next item (string or drawable) will appear beneath it, pushing it in an upward motion.

UPDATE

I made a Model and an Adapter

Here is the model

```
public class ModelC1 {

public String C1Name;
public String C1Text;
public int id;
public boolean isSend;

public ModelC1(String C1Name, String C1Text, int id, boolean isSend){
    this.id = id;
    this.C1Name = C1Name;
    this.C1Text = C1Text;
    this.isSend = isSend;
}

public int getId(){
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id){
    this.id = id;
}

public String getC1Name() {
    return C1Name;
}

public void setC1Name(String C1Name){
    this.C1Name = C1Name;
}

public String getC1Text() {
    return C1Text;
}

public void setC1Text (String C1Text){
    this.C1Text = C1Text ;
}

public boolean isSend() {
    return isSend;
}

public void setIsSend(boolean send){
    isSend = send;
}
```

Here is the Adapter

```
public class AdapterC1 extends BaseAdapter {

private List<ModelC1> listChat;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;

public AdapterC1(List<ModelC1> listChat, Context context){
    this.listChat = listChat;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listChat.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return listChat.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if(convertView == null ){
        if(listChat.get(i).isSend() == 0)
            vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_send,null);
        else if ((listChat.get(i).isSend() == 1))
            vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_recv,null);
        else if ((listChat.get(i).isSend() == 2))
            vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_mid,null);

    }else{
        if(listChat.get(i).isSend() == 0)
            vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_send,null);
        else if ((listChat.get(i).isSend() == 1))
            vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_recv,null);
        else if ((listChat.get(i).isSend() == 2))
            vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_mid,null);
    }

    if(listChat.get(i).isSend() !=0 || listChat.get(i).isSend() !=1 ||  listChat.get(i).isSend() !=2 ){
        BubbleTextView bubbleTextView = (BubbleTextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.bubbleChat);
        if(bubbleTextView != null)
            bubbleTextView.setText(listChat.get(i).C1Text);
        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.nameChat);
        if(nameTextView != null)
            nameTextView.setText(listChat.get(i).C1Name);
    }else{
        vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_mid,null);
        BubbleTextView bubbleTextView = (BubbleTextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.bubbleChat);
        bubbleTextView.setText("THE END");
    }

    return vi;
}
```

And here is the activity

public class Chat1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "Chat1";

```
private AdapterC1 adapter;
private List<ModelC1> listChat = new ArrayList<>();
private int count = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat1);

    RecyclerView chatContent1 = findViewById(R.id.chatContent1);
}

private ModelC1 setUpMessage(){
    Log.d(TAG, "setUpMessage: Exec");
    return();
}

///OnClick of the button in the activity_chat1.xml
public void nextClicked1(View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "nextClicked: Is Clicked");

    ///After the limit of the arraylist is reached
    final int limit = 40;
    if(count == limit){
        Log.d(TAG, "nextClicked: Limit Reached");

        Intent i = new Intent(Chat1.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }else{
        ///Call the list
        loadList(null);
    }
}

///Load the list of arrays?
public void loadList(View view){
    ModelC1 chat = setUpMessage();
    listChat.add(chat);
    ///The ID of the recycleview in the activity_chat1.xml
    final RecyclerView recyclerview = findViewById(R.id.chatContent1);
    ///The adapter
    final AdapterC1 adapter = new AdapterC1(listChat, this);
    ///Make the recyclerview always scroll

    ///the adapter
         ///recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

My questions are now how do I make the ArrayList (containing strings and drawables) and how to link the ArrayList to make it appear one by one when I click on the button ?

As for the ArrayList, will soemthing like that works ?

```
private List<List<String>> textChat1 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

ArrayList<String> textChat1 = new ArrayList<String>();
textChat1.add("This is message 1");
textChat1.add("This is message 2");
textChat1.add("This is message 2");
addresses.add(textChat1);
```

How can I add images and how to say which strings inflate which layout (left, mid or right) ?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Refer this solution.. It can be helpful for you for **Listview** [Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950438/3946958) and for the **Recyclview** [Recyclview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971350/recycle-view-inflating-different-row-getting-exception-while-binding-the-data/39972276#39972276)

Comment: @AdamOstrožlík Here it is, I was trying to understand how to complete it but I'm stuck

Answer (score 2):

You can do your job like this: in your `Adapter`'s `getView` method ,

```html
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            if (position == 1) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.left, container, false);
            } else if (position == 2) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mid, container, false);
            } else {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.right, container, false);
            }
        }
        //your code here
        return convertView;
    }
```

This will do your job, but, I suggest you to use `Recyclerview` because it's more efficient and better in terms of looks as well as memory management.

Comment: Thank you for the answer it helped me start the work! I've updated my post, can you help again?