# ViewHolder Pattern with Views inside Views shows duplicates

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a .xml file that is a row for a ListView and it has a layout included in it like this:

```
<relativeLayout>
           <Textview username blah blah/>
           <include
                android:id="@+id/like_button_layout"
                layout="@layout/like" />
<relativeLayout>
```

Now when I want to use ViewHolder pattern in my adapter, it shows duplicate values only for this "like" layout (which has an image and a textview inside it)
I can't figure out why. Here's the java code:

```
    private class ViewHolder {
            public TextView userName;
            public View likeButtonLayout;
        }

    @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            final Context context = parent.getContext();

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView =
                        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.panel_talk_topic, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.userName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);

                holder.likeButtonLayout = convertView.findViewById(R.id.like_button_layout);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            ImageView likeButtonImage =
                    holder.likeButtonLayout.findViewById(R.id.like_button_imageView);
            TextView likeCountText = holder.likeButtonLayout.findViewById(R.id.like_count_textView);
.
.
.
```

The usernames are all correct, but I think there needs to be a special way of inflating views inside views when using view holder pattern that I'm not aware of. Ideas?

Comment: Some questions.. why are you not using recycler view?? what is convertView?? and what do you mean by duplicates?? Please provide an example of the problem using logcats or a screenshot

Comment: I can't use recycler view, I expected to get this question. By duplicates I mean every 5 rows, the values inside likeCountText and likeButtonImage are similar to the previous rows. There is a pattern that is being repeated, however all userNames are different in each row.

Comment: I would like to know why you can't use recycler view

Comment: refer this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950438/3946958

Comment: none of the answers were helpful, but thanks :(

Answer (score 0):

This happens with recycler view, maybe it happens with list view also.. the thing is in recycler view, views are recycled and the one view holder is used again and again. That is why, the state of one view holder is persists.
What I generally do to solve it, is just reset the state in the first line of **onBindViewHolder()**